# Не работает скрипт в модальном окне

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужно сделать анимацию в модальном окне, которое появляется при клике на кнопку. В приведенном ниже коде, есть пример рабочей анимации.Как сделать так чтобы анимация работала и во всплывающем окне?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  const $div = $('#load-1');
  const MAX_ANGLE = -359;
  let angle = 0;
  const animate = () => {
    if (angle >= MAX_ANGLE) {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
    $div.css('transform', `rotate(${angle}deg)`);
    angle -= 3;
  }

  animate();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#load-1").attr("src", "https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/8/31/96bbb1518df72fed40351c0ba63688c0-full.png");
  }, 2500);

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.click').click(function() {
    $('body').append(
      "<div class='modal' style='width:500px; height: 500px;  background-color: red;'>" +
      "<div class='loader-content'>" +
      "<img src='https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/8/31/04b1f66f088ceaf6d6aa44902cd28bdf-full.png' id='load-1' class='load-img'>" +
      "<span>Header</span>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-6 loader-content">
  <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/8/31/04b1f66f088ceaf6d6aa44902cd28bdf-full.png" id="load-1" class="load-img" />
  <span>Header</span>
</div>
<button class="click">button</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запускайте анимацию после добавления html на страницу:

```js
function runLoadingAnimation(selector) {
  const $div = $(selector);
  const MAX_ANGLE = -359;
  let angle = 0;
  const animate = () => {
    if (angle >= MAX_ANGLE) {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
    $div.css('transform', `rotate(${angle}deg)`);
    angle -= 3;
  }

  animate();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(selector).attr("src", "https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/8/31/96bbb1518df72fed40351c0ba63688c0-full.png");
  }, 2500);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  runLoadingAnimation('#load-1');
});



$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.click').click(function() {
    $('body').append(
      "<div class='modal' style='width:500px; height: 500px;  background-color: red;'>" +
      "<div class='loader-content'>" +
      "<img src='https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/8/31/04b1f66f088ceaf6d6aa44902cd28bdf-full.png' id='load-2' class='load-img'>" +
      "<span>Header</span>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>")
    runLoadingAnimation('#load-2');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6 loader-content">
  <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/8/31/04b1f66f088ceaf6d6aa44902cd28bdf-full.png" id="load-1" class="load-img" />
  <span>Header</span>
</div>
<button class="click">button</button>
```

Comment: Все супер, спасибо!